# Using JS to check if child element contains value

Tags: javascript, css

I been searching but can't find a useful answer.

```css
.event [IF CHILD 'day' CONTAINS 'mon'] {background-color:blue;}
.event [IF CHILD 'day' CONTAINS 'thu'] {background-color:red;}
.event [IF CHILD 'day' CONTAINS 'wed'] {background-color:green;}
```

```html
<div class="event">
   <div class="day">mon</div>
</div>
<div class="event">
   <div class="day">thu</div>
</div>
<div class="event">
   <div class="day">wed</div>
</div>
```

This is basically what I would like to do. As far as I know this is not possible with pure CSS.

But it should be possible with JS, but I am not exactly sure how..

Anyone knowing how to do this?

Comment: Please be more specific, including what you have tried and what your are expecting.

Comment: Not an answer, but I think you may put those strings (mon, thu, ...) to the `data` attribute, which will make it accessible by css selectors

Answer (score 0):

You need to select all event with `querySelectorAll` then `forEach` and check if `textContent` of every day is equal to one of your choise like:

```js
const event = document.querySelectorAll('.event');
event.forEach(el => {
  var day = el.querySelector('.day');
  if (day.textContent === 'mon') {
    el.classList.add('blue');
  } else if (day.textContent === 'thu') {
    el.classList.add('red');
  } else if (day.textContent === 'wed') {
    el.classList.add('green');
  }
});
```

```css
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="event">
  <div class="day">mon</div>
</div>
<div class="event">
  <div class="day">thu</div>
</div>
<div class="event">
  <div class="day">wed</div>
</div>
```

Reference:

- [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question.

I do NOT need to change background on the "day" class. I need to change background on the "event" class, BUT according to the DAY inside the "event" class.

Makes sense?

If the day INSIDE the event is etc. "mon", I want to make the background color for EVENT class to etc. red.

Comment: that's just what the script does, `el` would be one of the `events` passed in the `foreach`, `el.classList.add('red'); === oneofevent.classList.add('red'); `

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: *Based on the OP's clarification*

You can change the parent style using JS as CSS always cascades down. To do it, simply get all the `day` class divs, iterate them, check the text and change the parent CSS as you want. I have used the `Switch` statement here. Each `case` represents the `day` div.

`node.parentNode` gets the parent `event` div of the current iterated `day` div and we change the style using JS.

Note: The example only shows two cases, please add more as you need.

**Working Code below:**

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div.day")).forEach(node => {
  switch (node.textContent) {
    case 'mon':
      node.parentNode.style.background = 'grey';
      break;
    case 'tue':
      node.parentNode.style.background = 'green';
      break;
    default:
      node.parentNode.style.background = 'white';
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="event">
  <div class="day" data-attr="mon">mon</div>
</div>
<div class="event">
  <div class="day" data-attr="tue">tue</div>
</div>
<div class="event">
  <div class="day" data-attr="wed">wed</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question.

I do NOT need to change background on the "day" class. I need to change background on the "event" class, BUT according to the DAY inside the "event" class.

Makes sense?

If the day INSIDE the event is etc. "mon", I want to make the background color for EVENT class to etc. red.

Answer (score 0):

You can create css rules with the innerText of each `.day` div, and then you can add the class to the `.event` div depending of the innerText of its child div:

```js
const eventDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.event');

for (const e of eventDivs) {
  const child = e.querySelector('.day')
  e.classList.add(`text-${child.innerText}`);
}
```

```css
.text-mon  {background-color:blue;}
.text-thu  {background-color:red;}
.text-wed  {background-color:green;}
```

```html
<div class="event">
   <div class="day">mon</div>
</div>
<div class="event">
   <div class="day">thu</div>
</div>
<div class="event">
   <div class="day">wed</div>
</div>
```

With Jquery it is even easier, and you can do it in-line:

```js
$('.event').each((_, e) => $(e).addClass(`text-${$(e).find('.day').text()}`));
```

```css
.text-mon  {background-color:blue;}
.text-thu  {background-color:red;}
.text-wed  {background-color:green;}
```

```html
<div class="event">
  <div class="day">mon</div>
</div>
<div class="event">
  <div class="day">thu</div>
</div>
<div class="event">
  <div class="day">wed</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question.

I do NOT need to change background on the "day" class. I need to change background on the "event" class, BUT according to the DAY inside the "event" class.

Makes sense?

If the day INSIDE the event is etc. "mon", I want to make the background color for EVENT class to etc. red.

Comment: @KennethHedegaard in the answer I'm changing the background color of the `.event` div.

Comment: Hi @AlexSp3 - this works, thanks! What if I want to use the .day's data-attr as selector instead of the innerText?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to do this with all pure javascript then this can help you or you can go with use of jquery as suggested in other answers

```
let allDivs = document.querySelectorAll("[class^=event]")

for (let i = 0; i < allDivs.length; i++) {
    let text = allDivs[i].textContent.trim();
    switch (text) {
        case 'mon':
            allDivs[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
            break;

        case 'thu':
            allDivs[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
            break;
        case 'wed':
            allDivs[i].style.backgroundColor = "green";
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question.

I do NOT need to change background on the "day" class. I need to change background on the "event" class, BUT according to the DAY inside the "event" class.

Makes sense?

If the day INSIDE the event is etc. "mon", I want to make the background color for EVENT class to etc. red.